# How can I limit the number of objects created per hour in Django?

Tags: django, object, limit, posts

The question is quite specific, is there any way to limit the user so that he can only create a number of objects per hour? I'm creating a social network and I need to be able to moderate spam.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
>>> from Django.utils import timezone
>>> a = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> filtered = Your_Model.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=a)
>>> print(filtered)
```

and then add a if statement like

```
if filtered.count() < 5:
    #you can publish
else:
    #you can't
```

Remember add __gte at the end of your datetime field when you are making the filter

Comment: Note, if you're only looking to use the length of the queryset as a logical test (meaning you don't need the actual objects for something else), then using the .count() method would allow the counting to be done in the database, which is usually much faster when things get big.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a third party package. This package provides the limitation of views for GET and POST request per IP https://github.com/sobotklp/django-throttle-requests.
Throttling the POST view will mean throttling object creation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using that package?

Comment: Essentially it melts down to creating middlewares and using the concept of caching to track down users. I like what @Mauricio suggested but still then for each request databases call will be executed and your system will be susceptible for DNS attack.